# How to copy files in laravel 5 controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, file-copying

I want copy file to folder in laravel.
when I copy file show me this error

> The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory

My code:

```
$success = \File::copy(base_path('test.text'),base_path('public/'));
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error says what it means. If you read the docs on the [copy()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_copy.asp) function it states you must copy from a file to a new file. Eg copying content from a .txt file to another.txt file.

So just add test.text after the public part and it will create a new file or overwrite an existing one.

```
$success = \File::copy(base_path('test.text'),base_path('public/test.text'));
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `public_path()` function to get the path to the `public/` folder you can copy that file like this

```
$destinationPath=public_path()."/UploadFolderName/FileName.ext";
$success = \File::copy(base_path('test.text'),$destinationPath);
```

now the `question` is where is your `source file`? if it is already in the `public folder` than you get the full path of that file like this.

```
$sourceFilePath=public_path()."/SomeFolderName/FileName";
$destinationPath=public_path()."//UploadFolderName/FileName.ext";
$success = \File::copy($sourceFilePath,$destinationPath);
```

Happy Coding!!!

**EDIT**

`public_path()` is `laravel` inbuilt function that give the full `path` of the `public` folder. for more information read here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-public-path